# Spring Security implementation preferably without spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Spring 4 MVC/REST application using AngularJS as the client side technology & Spring data mongoDB as server side.
I want to secure the application. All examples I see are based on Spring Boot.

Q1) Is it possible to secure a Spring 4 application without Spring Boot?

Q2) Is it possible to just include Sprint Boot for security alone in my Spring 4 application, so that we don't need to recode everything based on Spring Boot?

Could you point me to some samples?

Answer (score 3):

- Q1) of course
- Q2) I don't think that this is a good idea (but I am not sure whether I understood your question right)

Have a look at the [Spring Security Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/), it is Boot free:

- @see [Spring Security Reference: Chapter 3 "Java Configuration"](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jc) for Java Configuration
- @see [Spring Security Reference: Chapter 4 "Security Namespace Configuration"](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-config) for xml configuraton

Examples: Google "spring security 4 configuration example":

- hit 3): [Hello Spring MVC Security Java Config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/hellomvc.html)
- hit 4): [Spring Security 4 Hello World Annotation+XML Example](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-hello-world-annotation-xml-example/)

Comment: Thank you Ralph  for your prompt response. I will try to implement the way described in these links.

Comment: My open source project could provide another useful example (Spring 4 but no Spring Boot): https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml

Answer (score 0):

All you need is Spring Security not Spring Boot. for securing your application the best way to learn is start by reading [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web-app-security)